# Text to speech voices

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I see this has been asked in the past but I have not seen an answer that works. Text to speech uses a very slow hard to understand voice.
I followed http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=751169 and installed the enhanced Nitech HTS voices. I ran festival from the command line and can hear the new voices.
i tried editing the festival usr/share/festival/festival.scm file and added
(set! voice_default 'voice_nitech_us_rms_arctic_hts)
but when I do that and then try to get it to speak form my python program I get no speech out whatsoever. If I comment out that line my python program works just with the nasty voice.
I also added the festival.scm file to /etc (there was not one there) like mentioned in another answer but when I do that again my sound disappears.
I also tried modifying voices.scm and changing KAL to don but that still does not help.
I think I have tried everything mentioned here. Has anyone figured out how to fix this? I'm using diamondback on ubunto 10.10.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10842/text-to-speech-voices/) by [ringo42](https://answers.ros.org/users/651/ringo42/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2011-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Ringo,

I have a possible solution for you below but first here is a summary of what I tried.  I am using Ubuntu 10.04 with the festival debian packages obtained using the Synaptics package manager.

First I tried your scenario with the latest Diamondback debian packages and confirmed that I also get the slow low voice.  (I reported this a while back [as a bug](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4940).)

Next I tried it with the latest Electric beta debian packages and in this case, launching the sound_play node fails with the following error:

```
process[soundplay_node-2]: started with pid [5505]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/audio_common/sound_play/scripts/soundplay_node.py", line 49, in <module>
    from diagnostic_msgs.msg import DiagnosticStatus, KeyValue, DiagnosticArray
ImportError: No module named diagnostic_msgs.msg
[soundplay_node-2] process has died [pid 5505, exit code 1].
log files: /home/patrick/.ros/log/d13001dc-c1ef-11e0-9414-0022683b2a0b/soundplay_node-2*.log
```

The fix I have found that works with both Diamondback and Electric is to overlay the latest audio_common stack as follows:

```
$ cd /home/ringo/ros (or whatever your personal ROS directory is)
$ sudo apt-get install mercurial
$ hg clone `roslocate uri audio_common`
$ rosmake --rosdep-install audio_common
```

Then run:

```
$ rospack profile
```

in each of your terminal windows and try this test:

In the first terminal:

```
$ roslaunch sound_play soundplay_node.launch
```

and in the second terminal:

```
$ rosrun sound_play say.py "How do I sound now?"
```

**IMPORTANT**: In your Python program, you need to add a second argument to the SoundClient say() command.  So this:

```
self.soundhandle = SoundClient()
rospy.sleep(1)
self.soundhandle.say('Take me to your leader.')
```

becomes this:

```
self.soundhandle = SoundClient()
rospy.sleep(1)
self.soundhandle.say('Take me to your leader.', '')
```

The second argument is for specifying the voice, but I have only tried setting it to the null string.

Hope that works for you!

--patrick

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2011-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Per Lenander](https://answers.ros.org/users/1061/per-lenander/) on 2011-11-24**:
Running Ubuntu 11.04 with the latest audio_common stack, I had the same problem as described above. I applied the last part of the solution (Set the voice to the null string, or "" in C++) and this works for me.